# Find last row when we do paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having a grid in my aspx page, and set "Allow paging= true"

Now I want to get the last row record of the last page.

I tried the following code to get the 1st row record,

```
GridViewRow FirstRow = gdvData.Rows[0]; //getting 1st row of 1st page working fine    
GridViewRow LastRow = gdvData.Rows[gdvData.Rows.Count - 1]; //getting last row of last page is not works
```

Ex. grid contains 6 pages, I want to retrieve last record of the 6th page.

The above code retrieve the last record of the 1st page but here I want last row of 6th page only.

I want disable particular column in the last row of the last page.
any idea?

Comment: The `GridView` stores only the current page in ViewState, that's the purpose of paging. So you need to access the DataSource (if available) to get the content of the last page. Why do you need to access something that is not visible anyway?

Comment: if i use DataSource, is there any way to find the last row of the last page with paging..?

Comment: The `DataSource` is not available on postback, only if you databind the `GridView`. So the only way is to query your "datasource" which seems to be a database. Of course you could store the source in `Session`, however, i wouldn't recommend it just to be able to access it later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable a particular cell in that row, use the RowDataBound Event, in the handler method, check if the current page is the last one, and if true, get the cell you want, and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int RowCount = GridView.Rows.Count;
GridView.PageIndex = RowCount/items_per_page
```

Answer (score 0):

You should query the underlying data source (e.g. database), not the gridview itself...

Answer (score 0):

If your GridView is filled by a DataSet or DataTable:

```
int rowCount=((DataSet)Customer).Rows.Count;
```

If you are binding the list or array of objects then you can do the following:

```
int rowCount = ((Customer[])gv.DataSource).Count;
```